# TaskManagers are still up even after job execution completed in PerJob deployment mode

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying out Flink Per-Job deployment using docker-compose.

Configurations:

```
version: "2.2"
jobs:
  jobmanager: 
    build: ./
    image: flink_local:1.1
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: standalone-job --job-classname com.organization.BatchJob
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        parallelism.default: 2
  taskmanager:
    image: flink_local:1.1
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
        parallelism.default: 2
```

Flink image is extended with job.jar, Job executed successfully.

`JobManager` exited after the job is completed, but `TaskManager` is still running, which is not expected.

Any configurations have to be added to exit both `JobManager` and `TaskManger`?

Versions:

`Flink - 1.11.0`

`Java - 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

Find [discussion](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/202008.mbox/%3cCAJNyZN7=23r4r=+64MfckRkgpkZ2G2HO5Gss65rsnp2mK9xByA@mail.gmail.com%3e#archives) with Flink team here.

In short in externally managed system like standalone-job/manually brought up k8s cluster, task managers has to be terminated explicitly or the instance gets terminated after timeout period.

In native k8s deployment, the taskmanager gets termianted swiftly as expected.

Comment: in k8 env with flink operator task manager is getting terminated after finishing job , but job manager still in running state . how to get job manger getting terminated after job finished